# opcion de select seleccionado para editar registro

Tags: php, html, select

Tengo este formulario de edicion de datos que es muy parecido al insert, al momento de traer los datos de un registro, me funciona la mayoria, pero no se como traer el dato del select que estaba previamente seleccionado. Probe de esta manera pero me dice error, no especifica mucho.

Aca el codigo

```
<?php
    include_once 'conexion.php';

    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $id=(int) $_GET['id'];

        $buscar_id=$con->prepare('SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE id=:id LIMIT 1');
        $buscar_id->execute(array(
            ':id'=>$id
        ));
        $resultado=$buscar_id->fetch();
    }else{
        header('Location: index.php');
    }


    if(isset($_POST['guardar'])){
        $nombres=$_POST['nombres'];
        $apellidos=$_POST['apellidos'];
        $telefono=$_POST['telefono'];
        $ciudad=$_POST['ciudad'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $rol=$_POST['rol']; // campo rol
        $id=(int) $_GET['id'];

        if(!empty($nombres) && !empty($apellidos) && !empty($telefono) && !empty($ciudad) && !empty($email) && !empty($rol) ){
            if(!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
                echo "<script> alert('Email no valido');</script>";
            }else{
                $consulta_update=$con->prepare(' UPDATE clientes SET  
                    nombres=:nombres,
                    apellidos=:apellidos,
                    telefono=:telefono,
                    ciudad=:ciudad,
                    email=:email,
                    roles_id =:rol
                    
                    WHERE id=:id;'
                );
                $consulta_update->execute(array(
                    ':nombres' =>$nombres,
                    ':apellidos' =>$apellidos,
                    ':telefono' =>$telefono,
                    ':ciudad' =>$ciudad,
                    ':email' =>$email,
                    ':roles_id' =>$rol,
                    ':id' =>$id
                ));
                header('Location: index.php');
            }
        }else{
            echo "<script> alert('Los campos estan vacios');</script>";
        }
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Editar Cliente</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/estilo.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="contenedor">
        <h2>CRUD EN PHP CON MYSQL</h2>
        <form action="" method="post">


            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="nombres" value="<?php if($resultado) echo $resultado['nombres']; ?>" class="input__text">
                <input type="text" name="apellidos" value="<?php if($resultado) echo $resultado['apellidos']; ?>" class="input__text">
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="telefono" value="<?php if($resultado) echo $resultado['telefono']; ?>" class="input__text">
                <input type="text" name="ciudad" value="<?php if($resultado) echo $resultado['ciudad']; ?>" class="input__text">
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php if($resultado) echo $resultado['email']; ?>" class="input__text">
            </div>

            <br>

            <!-- SELECT DE ROLES -->
            <label for="rol">Choose a rol:</label>
            <div class="caja">


                <select name="rol">

                    <?php

                        // llamo a la conexion
                        include_once('conexion.php');

                        $select_rol = $con->prepare('SELECT id, descripcion FROM roles');

                        $select_rol->execute();

                        $rows = $select_rol->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);


                        // RECORRO LA TABLA
                        foreach ($rows as $row) {
                            
                        ?>      

                            

                            <option value="<?php echo $resultado[$rol] ?>" selected="selected"></option> // linea del error


                        <?php


                        }

                    ?>  
                    

                    

                </select>


            </div>


            <div class="btn__group">
                <a href="index.php" class="btn btn__danger">Cancelar</a>
                <input type="submit" name="guardar" value="Guardar" class="btn btn__primary">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: cual es la descripcion de el error ?¿

Comment: Tenes un error en las asignaciones.

Dentro del foreach deberias imprimir $row[] y estas queriendo obtener un $resultado[] que no pertenece a esa consulta

$rol es el campo de la consulta (general) para el form
y cual sería el campo que comparas en la consulta del select? $row['?']